# Problem with configuring ssl certificates in asp .net core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate

I have the following certificates
[Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxx9n.png)

I want to configure my asp .net core web API to use these certificates in order to use https redirection. I am using Kestrel for the app settings.

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://jj.com:5002"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to do it by myself while reading some online posts, but no result.
Here is my Configure method in Startup.cs file.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerManager logger)
        {

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "General API");
                c.SupportedSubmitMethods();
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }


            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action}");
            });
        }
```

Here is my Program.cs file content:

```
  public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(
                context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));


            }).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseSetting("https_port", "443");

                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                {
                    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
                o.ClientCertificateMode =
                    ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
                });

            }).UseWindowsService();

    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated !

Comment: you haven't told it where your cert is... see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you problem correctly, you just want to have https on kestrel. what you can do is to add following setting on appsetting.json

`"HTTPS_PORT": "5151", "Kestrel": { "EndpointDefaults": { "Protocols": "Http1" }, "Certificates": { "Default": { "Path": "server_cert.pfx", "Password": "password" } } },`

For this line  `o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);`
Only use it if you want to use Client Certificate.